# Get the string field modification before it's update

Tags: python, openerp-7

I'have a String Field called 'sujet' in my class reclamation.I ve been trying to get the field value before it's update this way i will know what's the words that have been added or deleted from my field by comparing the filed value before and after the update

Exemple_1: Field Sujet before Hitting the save button 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDm3y.png

Exemple_2: Field Sujet after Hitting the save button 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W74zA.png

output:The change to my field is: added "is the best community"

For this I instantly thought about overwriting the write() method like the following:

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, values, context=None):
        _logger.error("*******************OnUpdate***********************")
        #code before update print field sujet value
        _logger.error("Before:%s",values['sujet'])
        res = super(reclamation, self).write(cr, uid, ids, values, context=context)
        #code after update print field sujet value
        _logger.error("Before:%s",values['sujet'])
        return res
```

The major problem  i'm facing is that when i print the value before the update i always have the value that comes after the update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved i was doing it wrong.
Well to better understand the solution we need to understand the write() method values paramater.Values contains the new String in my case "stackoverflows community is the best community". In order to get the field ancient value we need obviously to query the database before the update query.

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, values, context=None):
    _logger.error("*******************OnUpdate***********************")
    obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    _logger.error("Before:%s",obj.sujet)
    res = super(reclamation, self).write(cr, uid, ids,values,context=context)        
    _logger.error("After:%s",values['sujet'])
    return res
```

Hope the solution help someone in the future and as they say.Read the Documentation